# Why is CBD legal in UK, Ireland, etc but it is Illegal to advertise it?

Tags: england-and-wales, medical, freedom-of-speech, medical-marijuana, ireland

Why can't you advertise CBD on Facebook, Google, etc., considering there is no THC and it is not a drug?

Comment: "illegal to advertise" is not the same as "This advertiser refuses my business".

Answer (score 2):

CBD most definitely is a drug and a chemical derived from marijuana. It may be a legal medicinal drug under the laws of [the UK](http://news.sky.com/story/cannabis-ingredient-to-be-classed-as-medicine-in-uk-10714967) and [Ireland](https://www.endoca.com/blog/tag/is-cbd-legal-in-ireland/) (two completely separate sovereign countries by the way) which just set their respective policies on the subject earlier this year, but that doesn't mean that it isn't a drug, and like many drugs it will require a prescription.

In any case, the UK and Ireland are not bound by the vigorous first amendment protections of the USA, and even the U.S. heavily regulates the advertising of medicinal drugs in order to protect the public from misleading claims in this commercial form of speech.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I understand how that works and the different laws. What I'm not understanding is how some places sell it as a food supplement [fruugo](https://goo.gl/XgDfFF) and if you search for CBD oil in Google, they show up as ads in the sidebar. From what I can see the website is UK based.

Yet I've tried to place an ad in Ireland with google for [fightstore](https://fightstoredublin.ie/product-category/brand/canavape-brand/) and it was turned down. Then I've tried to do the same with Facebook and they came back saying I was promoting illegal drugs.

Comment: After I messaged them asking for an explanation, they came back with the same message 'You are promoting illegal drugs... and we will not reply to any of your messages'. They can't tell me why... that's odd.

Comment: Perhaps you need to have ads pre-approved by their respective versions of the FDA before they can be used. Also, enforcement systems don't have to be flawless. There gap be enforcement gaps and loopholes due to inadvertence and all sorts of other means.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try and see if I can find a loophole around it.